# charAt() returning weird values

Tags: java, charat

I am trying to make program that convert number to words but when I use charAt(0) to get the value of index 0 its returning me strange values

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class numToWord {
    public static   void main(String[] args) {

        String[] digit = {"Zero","One ","Two", "Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ", "Seven ", "Eight ", "Nine" };
        Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
        String strNum = sc.next(); //input 123
        int intnum = Integer.valueOf(strNum.charAt(0));
        System.out.println(intnum);
        System.out.println(digit[intnum]);
        //output 49

    }
}
```

example input  123
output 49

[Input Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNVCd.png)

Comment: What exactly is strange? If you input the string `"5"`, it consists of a single character, `'5'`, which has a codepoint of 53 in most encodings.

Comment: why its returning codepoint it's supposed to char right ?

Comment: What do *you* think a `char` should contain? It contains the codepoint of a character (well, technically it could be just a surrogate pair, but that's the exception, for most commonly used characters `char` = codepoint holds true).

Comment: And after printing out the 'incorrect' value, the program will crash with an out-of-bounds array index, since there are not 54 elements in the digit array.  (Oh, I didn't look at the linked picture of the output until now - yup, it crashed as expected).

Comment: ``char`` is an integer type in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**valueOf()** is used for string conversion not for **char** type.

If you want to convert a **char** value to an **integer** using **valueOf()** it's always return the **[ASCII value](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)** of it. Use **Character.getNumericValue()** to solve this problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class numToWord{
    public static   void main(String[] args) {
        String[] digit = {"Zero","One ","Two", "Three ","Four ","Five ","Six ", "Seven ", "Eight ", "Nine" };
        Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
        String strNum = sc.next();
        //int intnum = Integer.valueOf(strNum.charAt(0));
        int intnum = Character.getNumericValue(strNum.charAt(0));
        System.out.println(intnum);
        System.out.println(digit[intnum]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are currently reading the ascii value of the first character of your input. Also, you have spaces in your digit mapping. What you wanted to do was parse each digit and get the mapping. Something like,

```
String[] digit = { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", 
        "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine" };
Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
String strNum = sc.next();
for (int i = 0; i < strNum.length(); i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    int v = Character.digit(strNum.charAt(i), 10); // strNum.charAt(i) - '0'
    System.out.print(digit[v]);
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up what ASCII is.

The character `'1'` maps to the decimal value `49` on the ASCII chart.

[image: ASCII chart]